# Identity involving $\arcsin$ and $\sin$.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin z = \sin \left(\arcsin \frac{\pi}{6} - \arccos \frac{\pi}{6} \right)$$

Is there a specific expansion of the expression on the right hand side of the equation? To evaluate the value of $z$?

Comment: $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$

Comment: $\sin(\arcsin \frac {\pi} 6) = \frac {\pi}6$

Comment: I reformatted your expression, adding a ")" in the middle on the right. Is everything in the "sin"? If so, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Bye_World, this looks like the trigonometric identity:

$$\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta - \cos \alpha \sin \beta \tag{1}$$

Since you already have:

$$arcsin \frac{\pi}{6} \Rightarrow \sin \alpha = \frac{\pi}{6} \tag{2}$$
$$arccos \frac{\pi}{6} \Rightarrow \cos \beta = \frac{\pi}{6} \tag{3}$$

You can then calculate the opposite sides:

$$\cos \alpha = \sqrt{1 - (\frac{\pi}{6})^2} \tag{4}$$
$$\sin \beta = \sqrt{1 - (\frac{\pi}{6})^2} \tag{5}$$

If you replace $(2, 3, 4, 5)$ in $(1)$, you now have:

$$\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \frac{\pi^2}{18} - 1 \tag{6}$$

The value of $z$ is therefore the $\arcsin$ of $(6)$.